# Python Pandas: Creating a column in a dataframe out of three different values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I need to create a column which will serve as an ID.
The ID should look like this:

ABC_7234Ij234XZ_03.02.2021

The first part is ABC_ and constant
The second part 7234Ij234XZ is stored in a column in the dataframe already as a [customer_number] which will be changing for each row
The third part is _03.02.2021 and constant

How can I add all three parts together in a new column called my_id where the second part is ever changing like the row demands while the first and last part are constant?

I'd be happy if somebody could nudge me in the right direction, as I couldn't find a solved question regarding such a constellation.
Thank you already in advance.

Comment: Did you try `df['ID'] = 'ABC_' + df['customer_number'] + '_03.02.2021'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
df['my_id'] = 'ABC_' + df['customer_number'].astype(str) + '_03.02.2021'
```